# Paste a webpage in Gmail body

Tags: gmail, html

How do I send an HTML page in Gmail?

I want to send the HTML page in Gmail to somebody. I tried to copy the HTML code and pasted in the email’s body, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean the code or the rendered output?

Comment: i need rendered output of html page

Comment: I assume you tried pasting the rendered output, right? As in click anywhere in the page, `ctrl`+`A`, `ctrl`+`C` and then pasting it into the Gmail compose window.

Comment: @Alex yes and also i pasted the HTML code directly

Comment: @MeerDeen: Gmail doesn't recognize HTML tags (code) inserted in the body of a message.

Comment: That’s strange, because I _can_ paste the content of a page in the compose window and it works fine. Could you add some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

To get the contents of the HTML into an email:

1. Put the HTML into a text file;
2. Attache the text file to the email.

Comment: That will be sent as attachment not a rendered output

Answer (score 0):

Must the page you insert be interactive? If not, use Snipping Tool (on Windows) and screen cap the site, then insert the resulting image into your email.

Comment: I just need html page to insert

Comment: Does it have to be interactive or just a still picture of the page?